# How can I prevent an organic group administrator from accessing edit page of a group?

Tags: 6, organic-groups, users

I want them to be able to post content only, not edit the group itself.  I'm using og_read_only so they can only post content to their own group as well.  This module has a problem though, you have to select which content types are read only each time you create a group, and if you add content types, you have to edit all of your groups again and check off the new content type as read only.

Is there a module that can prevent the group admin from accessing the group edit page?  Would that module also be able to prevent the admin from posting to a group that they are not a member of?

I will accept an answer if it only covers preventing the group admin from accessing the edit page.  I was just hoping the other issue might be covered by the same module since they both seem related to access control.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use rules to redirect users that aren't admins to another page, or use `hook_menu_alter()` to alter the access permissions to the page. Alternatively, you can use `hook_page_alter()` to check the active user's roles and redirect them if they aren't in the admin group.